# Is mclapply() with mc.cores = 1 the same as lapply()?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mclapply

I know that I should not nest parallel operators, but I am in a situation where I have to basically nest two `mclapply()` calls in my code. 
This is because in my code I have a function (let's call it `foo()`) that is already using `mclapply()` inside it. What I want is basically to run parallel threads of a sequential version of `foo()`, doing something like this:

```
mclapply(X, function(x) {
  foo(x, mc.cores = 1)
},
mc.cores = 4)
```

Can I just run the internal `mclapply()` with `mc.cores = 1` or I should implement a sequential version of `foo()`?

In other words: is `mclapply(..., mc.cores = 1)` behaving exactly as `lapply(...)`? Is there a parallel overhead slowing down the program in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The source code of `parallel::mclapply` contains this bit of code:

```
 ... 
 if (cores < 2L) 
        return(lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...))
 ...
```

So I believe the answer is yes, you should get the same results as using `lapply` directly, but there is also some additional overhead. I doubt that this will affect the runtime very significantly.

The documentation also states that:

> Details
>
> mclapply is a parallelized version of lapply, provided mc.cores > 1:
>   for mc.cores == 1 it simply calls lapply.